# Update values of one list<T> by another list<T>

Tags: c#, list

I have a single List of Airplane objects inside of an Airport object. As below, I put the main List into five different Lists of Airplanes for some processing later on.

```
        List<Airplane> crashedQueue = Airport.AirportPlanes.FindAll(s => s._state == "Crashed");
        List<Airplane> intransitQueue = Airport.AirportPlanes.FindAll(s => s._state == "Circling");
        List<Airplane> enteringCirclingQueue = Airport.AirportPlanes.FindAll(s => s._state == "Entering Circling");
        List<Airplane> landedQueue = Airport.AirportPlanes.FindAll(s => s._state == "Landed");
        List<Airplane> intransitQueue = Airport.AirportPlanes.FindAll(s => s._state == "In-Transit");
```

After all the five lists are complete processing separately, i want to update the main Airplane list, which is inside the Airport object (Airport.AirportPlanes) with the new values in the five Airplane lists.

Comment: Where is your question mark?

Comment: Hard to guess why this is necessary.  If "processing" means changing the _state member then you don't have to do anything.  Just make sure that Airplane is a class and not a struct.

Comment: no no.. actually theres more than that.. depending on their states, i update different different values in different different lists by performing  calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Airport.AirportPlanes = crashedQueue
                        .Union(intransitQueue)
                        .Union(enteringCirclingQueue)
                        .Union(landedQueue)
                        .Union(intransitQueue)
                        .ToList()
```

Or you can also use `.AddRange` method

```
intransitQueue.AddRange(intransitQueue)....
```

Once you're done with the updates.

Answer (score 0):

```
Airport.AirportPlanes = crashedQueue.Concat(intransitQueue).Concat(...)
```